# Зачем нужно создавать два класса для создания одного потока?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Пример из книги Шилдта Java для начинающих, ответа пока не нашел в ней.

*Заранее спасибо за ответ!*

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
   String thrdName;

   MyThread(String name) {
       thrdName = name;
   }


    public void run() {
       System.out.println(thrdName + " - launch");
       try {
           for(int  count=0; count <10; count++) {
               Thread.sleep(400);
               System.out.println(" In " + thrdName+" counter: " + count);
           }

       } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
           System.out.print(thrdName + " - stopped");
       }
       System.out.println(thrdName + " Ending");

    }

}


public class UseThreads {


     public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Launch main flow ");
        MyThread mt = new MyThread("FLOW 1");
        Thread newThrd = new Thread(mt);
        newThrd.start();

        for (int i =0; i<50; i++) {
            System.out.print(".");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                System.out.print("Stopping of main Flow");
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Ending of main flow");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разумеется, не обязательно создавать два класса для создания отдельного потока. Это скорее касается архитектурного решения.

Обратимся к первому принципу SOLID - **Single Responsibility Principle**

> Класс должен быть ответственен лишь за что-то одно. Если класс отвечает за решение нескольких задач, его подсистемы, реализующие решение этих задач, оказываются связанными друг с другом. Изменения в одной такой подсистеме ведут к изменениям в другой.

Здесь же в примере : `UseThreads` - это точка входа в приложение, а `MyThread` - это счетчик. У двух этих классов разные предназначения, а следовательно, хорошо, что они разделены.

Разумеется, в таком маленьком примере это, возможно, трудно понять, но с практикой - такие вещи будут очевидными. Рекомендую почитать про принципы SOLID.

Comment: ого ! незнал что принципы есть такие , я про solid. Спасибо за совет!)

Answer (score 3):

Первый класс тот, что имплементриует `Runnable` в теле метода `run()` описывает работу потока. Сам поток этот класс не создаёт. Потом отдельно создаётся сам поток

```
Thread newThrd = new Thread(mt);
```

`mt` - что поток будет делать(грубо говоря). В книге именно этот способ приведён, потому что он нагляднее, способ в котором логика в одном классе, а исполнитель этой логики в другом.  Есть второй способ создания потоков, можно унаследоваться от Thread и таким образом будет создан поток "одним классом".